# Why is it better to use this@MyActivity than this when referring to a context?

Tags: android, kotlin

I heard somewhere that it was better practice to refer to a context like this `context = this@MyActivity` than doing like that `context = this`. While I don't debate it (I really can't since I don't understand it yet), I want to know exactly what is the difference between the two and why one is better than the other if that's even true?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a read of this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html Basically `this` refers to the object whose *scope* you're directly inside, so you can explicitly access its variables, functions etc., or just refer to the object itself like you're doing here. You can also nest scopes (e.g. using `run` on another object) so the `@MyActivity` bit lets you explicitly refer to a different scope in the hierarchy. That's the only time you'd **need** to qualify `this`, when using it alone would give you the wrong object. As for always doing it as best practice, that's completely subjective!

Comment: It isn't best practice.  It is necessary however if you're in a nested scope inside of MainActivity-  there's no other way to reference it, because the local this of that scope is a different object.